# ionic 2.3.0 cant install plugin via npm

Tags: ionic2

i try to install the plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information" (as administrator) via

> npm install --save @ionic-native/network

the process stops at:

> / postinstall: info lifecycle @ionic-native/network@4.2.1~postinstall: @ionic-native/network@4.2.1

and i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\path\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\path\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\path\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\path\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\ansi-regex\\package.json\'\n    
at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\path\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\ansi-
regex\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-05T09_43_58_528Z-debug.log
```

Info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\username.npm-packages\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.3.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.9.4
npm  : 5.4.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Please help.

Comment: same Problem if i try "npm i" :-(

Answer (score 0):

CrossPost, sorry ;-) but get a solution:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-install-plugin/104286/2